# Do all printers have Linux operating system in them so they can have colour LCD, network and USB support?

Tags: embedded, linux

I have found that recently all printers have a complex GUI on small LCD. Also, for a long time now, they have had network and USB support. Now they can also connect via WiFi and print directly from email or google drive e.t.c.

I am curious to know, how does this work? Do all printers have some sort of Linux on them so they can do all these things? Do they need some sort of GPU to do the complex GUI portion?

Comment: Many do have *some* OS, and embedded Linux would be a popular choice. You can't tell for *all* of them. They do *not* have GPU of course as the "complex" GUI is not that complex at all.

Comment: FreeRTOS gives USB, WiFi, Ethernet, LCD etc. And it is **not Linux**.  There are many embedded OSes that are not Linux that will give said functionality.

Comment: @Eugene, the GUIs look complex with so many colors and buttons, there might not be a need for Nvidia GTX 1080p for that, but certainly some form of dedicated hardware with some specialized graphics drawing capability will be required for that.

Comment: Number of on-screen elements does not require any extra computational power. GPUs are used for fast parallel processing when the content is dynamic and it's dynamics are complex. Which is not the case for most GUIs, unless these have some very fancy special effects, such as 3D, complex animations, transparency and such.

Comment: I don't know why I got all down votes, the question was about electronic design since I don't know how the printer and other devices are able to do what they do.

Answer (score 4):

No, all printers do not have Linux.  Some do, some have other operating systems, some have proprietary control code.

I can't say definitively but a GPU is highly unlikely as the UI for printers is relatively simple and a GPU would be an expensive add-on for little to no benefit.

If a printer does have a GPU, it would be used in the image rendering portion of the printing function, not the UI on a small LCD display.

But again, there may be exceptions for some high-end printers.

Answer (score 0):

No - not all printers have Linux. Linux is not needed for any network, USB or graphical display support. And a GPU is not needed for display support, only a simple display controller is needed - but as displays may have a display controller built-in so the MCU does not need to have one.

Comment: What does a display controller actually do? The fancy menus I have seen so far require some form of dedicated hardware for sure.

Comment: A simple display controller would be a unit that has a "frame buffer" - that is a memory containing data to display (or an interface to external memory) and the display interface to feed that data to the display itself. +some control interface with the main processor. So the content "fed" into the frame-buffer is calculated and provided by the main processor, unlike the GPU, which is performing fancy calculations by itself.